# How to connect a cpannel hosted database to vercel hosted nextjs app?

Tags: postgresql, next.js, cpanel, prisma

I've deployed my next js 14 app to vercel. and for the api route i'm using prisma ORM. and today i started using cpannel and tried to use it's postgresql and connect it to Nextjs app with prisma. but i really have no idea how to do that. |

i've already created a database in cpannel and connected it to a user. and i used Shared IP Address in host and 5432 for the port. coz i know this is the format of the url.

```
postgresql://user:password@host:port/database
```

but after connecting this and tried doing `npx prisma db push` and it throws an error

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database

Error: P1013: The provided database string is invalid. invalid port number in database URL. Please refer to the documentation in https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/connection-urls for constructing a correct connection string. In some cases, certain characters must be escaped. Please check the string for any illegal characters.
```

so how do i connect it? NOTE: i'm a begginer when it comes to cpannel. today is my first day.